# How to "Data and a button in same column with kendo grid"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible? I tried with custom column, but I failed, can anyone give a simple example for it with razor ?

**Paint work :)**

I want something like that, column include data and a button( with onclick )

[image]

```
//---Not Worked 1---

    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Custom("Telefonları Göster").Click("telefonlariGoster");
        columns.Bound(x => x.Adres);
    }).Width(580);
....

//---Not worked 2---

        columns.Template(@<text>
            <label>@item.Adres</label>
            <input type="button" name="AdresGuncelle" value="AdresGuncelle" onclick="telefonlariGoster()" />
    </text>);

//Worked

columns.Bound(x => x.Adres)
     .ClientTemplate("#=Adres#" +
     "<input type='button' class='telefonlariGoster' style='float: right;' name='telefonlariGoster' value='Telefonları Güncelle' onclick='telefonlariGoster()'/>");
```

Comment: I don't know about buttons, but it seems that Kendo supports event handling. Just target your column via css and give each row in that column a "button look". You can find all about event handling on http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/events.html

Comment: It is logical but there must be a way to do my wish.

Comment: If you could post your code, I would be able to help a bit more, but as it is, you will have to get by with my answer and the docs.

Comment: I just realized you wanted a command INSIDE a field. Disregard my previous answer. My apologies.

Comment: Exactly, command inside a field:)
By the way I read links which you give, many times before, there isn't any structure like i want to do, there.
Very thanks for your attention and replies.

Comment: Have you tried nesting a `field` and `command` together inside curly braces? Something like : `{field: "Your field text", command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }, title: " Your title ", width: "140px" }`

Comment: I had tried something like that but it failed, I m trying yours now

Comment: Can you write it again for razor ?

Comment: `columns.Command(command => {
        command.Custom("viewDetails").Click("showDetails");
        command.Custom("AnotherCommand").Text("Another Command");
        command.Custom("Custom").Text("Custom Command");
    });`
Try this.. this would add three buttons. After seeing if it works AT  ALL, you will know we are on the right track. I do not have kendo, so I am trying on pure instinct.

Comment: I had tried it before( I wrote my code to question ), but result is http://i41.tinypic.com/5mibfs.jpg

Comment: Why not try closing the "command=>" curly brace before writing your bound? Second, the order in which you wrote your `command` and `bound` is reversed. From what I see in your paint work, you want the text first, and the button after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use ClientTemplate of column where you want display your custom column display.
For example:

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(x => x.Name)
          .ClientTemplate("#=Name#" +
          "<input type='button' class='className' style='float: right;' name='buttonName' value='Click here' onclick='ButtonClick(\"#=Name#\", this)'/>");
      columns.Bound(x => x.Id);
  })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                               .Ajax()
                               .Total(10)
                               .ServerOperation(false)
                             )
  )
```

in script button click function

```js
function ButtonClick(name, button) {
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the what i want

Comment: @Goran_Mandic You right, both of you deserve an upvote, Thanks a lot :)